# Connecting Ground Paths

Tags: ground-plane

I am using a stm32f407vgtx to control full bridge drivers which drive a H bridge of 4 N-channel Mosfet. I don't have any idea about grounding.
I am thinking of using two separate ground AGND (ground of 5V ) and PGND (power ground 24V) then I will connect them together with a Net Tie.

*_* am i on the right path.
*_* Any advice or reference can help me (grounding consideration).

Thank You.

Best Regards

Comment: A schematic would really help to understand your question. Usually the output clamps of a h-bridge are not grounded, but I don't think that's what you are asking for...

Comment: You don't want your 24V power currents to flow in your 5V logic grounds. A single point connection between the 2 grounds will prevent this. If you highlight the high current paths on your schematic, it should help you find the best location to connect the 2 grounds.

Comment: @ Mattman944 . Thank you but I don't know how to find the location to connect them can you help plz.

Comment: @ Sim Son .thank you

Comment: Search for the concept of „star grounding“ on this site or elsewhere. You will find a lot of info.